# IMPORTXML Function doesn't work for this page

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I'm trying to do a personal search and would like to get some data (Number of players, Number of reviews, Category etc), from the single-game page of BoardGameGeek Website (https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/174430/gloomhaven).

Unfortunately, the IMPORTXML Google Spreadsheet function doesn't work and I don't understand why. Maybe the page is JS generated? I'm not an expert, does anyone have a solution? I have looked in other treads but it seems to me a rather specific case.

Answer (score 1):

IMOPORTXML formula (or any other IMPORT formula) does not support the scrapping of JavaScript elements. you can always test this by disabling JS for a given site and usually only what is left can be imported. in your case its pure JS:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: @CarloAlberto with different url that hosts same data you may be more lucky